# How do I install my Canon CanoScan LiDE 20 scanner to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit?

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon

I purchased a Canon CanoScan LiDE 20 scanner in the middle of 2005.

At the time, I had a 32-bit computer with Microsoft Windows XP 32-bit installed on it.

Now, I have a 64-bit computer with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit installed on it.

I can't scan with my Canon CanoScan LiDE 20 scanner using this installation of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could please provide me with instructions to install my Canon CanoScan LiDE 20 scanner on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit so that I can scan with it.

I'm new to Ubuntu so I won't understand how to install this scanner if steps that more experienced users of Ubuntu take for granted are missed.

Thanks a lot for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: This is a USB device, yes? Is it plugged directly to a computer USB2 port? Edit your question and show me `lsusb`. What application have you tried to scan with?

Answer (score 2):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: I've forgotten my manners.  I'm sorry.  Thanks a lot for this assistance that you've provided to me.  May I please ask you if you are saying that you believe that I should be able to get my 32-bit Canon CanoScan LiDE 20 scanner working with any version of Ubuntu 64-bit into the foreseeable future?  Is is possible that forces beyond my control may prevent me from doing this?  Rightly or wrongly, if I can't get this perfectly good 32-bit scanner (in immaculate condition) working with Ubuntu 64-bit, then I'm not going to use Ubuntu 64-bit.  I'll go back to using Windows and LibreOffice.